# CATIAV6 Generate STEP information for assembly in xml format- .stpx

Tags: catia, step

I have a requirement to use the STEP data of an assembly / physical product as .stpx type. How is it possible to achieve in CATIAV6. Is it possible to convert .stp to .stpx format?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got it by selecting the output type as .stpx while running the batch util.